# nmcli freedesktop DBus warnings and errors

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, d-bus, freedesktop, nmcli

As soon as I do `nmcli con up id <ESSID>`, I experience some warnings/errors:

> ** (process:4841): WARNING **: async_got_type: could not read properties for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5:
>   Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface
>   "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
>
> ** (process:4841): WARNING **: async_got_type: could not read properties for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5:
>   Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface
>   "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
>
> ** (process:4841): WARNING **: async_got_type: could not read properties for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5:
>   Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface
>   "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
>
> Error: Connection activation failed: Creating object for path
>   '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5' failed in
>   libnm-glib.

- How can I fix this error?
- What causes this?

I have (X)Ubuntu 13.10.

This might have to do something with some `freedesktop` related issues, I have with recently. Please have a look at it, too: [Gnome programs (eog/gnome-terminal) have a slow start and produce a DBus.Error.NoReply Warning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145167/72471).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to what extent this is applicable, but I am running Debian 8 with XMonad as my window manager instead of Gnome, so I use nmcli/nmtui to connect to wireless networks. This is by no means a solution or an explanation, but merely a workaround:

- When possible, use `nmtui`
- Otherwise, run `nmcli con edit id` and `set` whatever fields are required (e.g. network password) and `save persistent`, then `activate` and `quit`.

Let me know if this works for you, I would be interested in finding an actual explanation and solution as well.