# What is the best way to find the current DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY in non interactive shell for the current user?

Tags: x11, xorg, variable, display

I have a project that needs to detect the `DISPLAY` in shell ([bash](/questions/tagged/bash)) variable to be able to display some [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) stuff on the local machine.

Or a better solution ([dbus](/questions/tagged/dbus) ?) to open [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) stuff in non interactive shell without trying to figure out `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`.

I can set `DISPLAY=:0` but that will fail if a user uses another session.

As far as I'm not in interactive mode, what I tried (works well, but only as root) is:

```
strings /proc/$(pidof Xorg)/environ | grep -Eo 'DISPLAY=:[0-9]+(:[0-9])*'
```

or as user:

```
ps uww $(pidof Xorg) | grep -oE '[[:blank:]]:[0-9]+(:[0-9])*\b'
```

But I don't know if it's reliable on any Linux (Unixes?)

**Is there a more reliable/portable way?**

Comment: What if there is no X server running on the machine, but X is forwarded from another machine (e.g. using `ssh -X`)?

Comment: I try to deal only with local X session, but if you have a magic trick to deal both on local and remote, welcome

Comment: For the same user, I think it's not necessary to force `XAUTHORITY` (tested with `zenity` in `cron`)

Comment: The same user may have an additional authentication with `xhost` Check the output of `xhost`, remove the entry with `xhost -SI:localuser:USERNAME` and try again. `xhost` entries can be given, but do not rely on them.

Comment: What's strange is that if I force `XAUTHORITY` to what I fetched from Xorg command or other places, in cron, I get error 'Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused' (with the good DISPLAY and the same user)

Comment: I can get this with valid `XAUTHORITY` but differences in network or hostname, not sure why this happens to you. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/25280523/5369403, try to insert `ffff` into the cookie. Like: `xauth nlist :0 -f $XAUTHORITY | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth -f /tmp/mycookie nmerge - ` and afterwards use `XAUTHORITY=/tmp/mycookie`

Comment: @Gilles: the solution provided in your link require to be root : `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/<PID>/environ` and I need to automating fetching this as user and with n > 1 Xorgs instances

Comment: Edited post with the same information

Comment: Uh? No, that thread is about accessing the display of the same user, there's no need to be root.

Comment: It don't provide a full workable snippet like I does below, and I tried code from that other post with the PID of Xorg, that is run as root (my bad). Moreover, the post is all about _remote X display_, this is not the case here, it's all local X display

Comment: What should happen if the machine uses several DISPLAYs (not common today, but still done), and the same user is logged in on more than one of them? (This also explains why there is no **portable** way to do this: You **shouldn't** be able to display something on the display of some user, even if the same user, without explicit permission).

Comment: Good question, I try to deal with this case, and the DISPLAY is correctly detected. I tested it as well. If the user install my project, he knows that some GUI will be displayed in his **own** session. Check my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image] Final solution not requiring to be root, and accessible from a non-interactive shell in an automated way and more advanced and usable than *possible duplicate* link provided earlier :

-`XAUTHORITY` :

```
ps -u $(id -u) -o pid= |
  xargs -I{} cat /proc/{}/environ 2>/dev/null |
  tr '\0' '\n' |
  grep -m1 '^XAUTHORITY='
```

- `DISPLAY` :

```
ps -u $(id -u) -o pid= |
  xargs -I{} cat /proc/{}/environ 2>/dev/null |
  tr '\0' '\n' |
  grep -m1 '^DISPLAY='
```

The snippet list all user's `pids`, iterate over them, then break on the first match

Based on [this](https://superuser.com/a/975536/68500)

Answer (score 7):

On distributions with init system `systemd` the output of

```
systemctl --user show-environment
```

shows `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`. This is at least true for my debian 9 system with systemd and `gdm3` as display manager.

Pitfall: After running `startx xterm -- :2 vt2` on tty2 systemctl gave me `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` from the new display; my main display `:0` was no longer observably this way.

---

Other approaches:

At least for `XAUTHORITY` it is more reliable to parse the output of `ps aux | grep Xorg` and look for option `-auth`. In my case it is located at `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority` and not at `~/.Xauthority`.

Pitfalls:

- There can be more than one Xorg instance.
- Instead of Xorg there can be `Xwayland`.
- Instead of Xorg there can be `Xvfb` or something else.
- It may be a remote session without local Xorg at all.

Normally `Xorg` commands also contain the display number. Unfortunately, mine does not:

```
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

`-displayfd 3` somehow points to `DISPLAY`. If looking as root at `/proc/$(pidof Xorg)/fd/3` I find

```
    lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mär  8 22:45 3 -> socket:[21437]
```

Though, I don't know how to look for socket `21437`. I am sure it points to `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`. One approach is `lsof +E -aUc Xorg` that shows interesting output: many connections containing `@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` and one `dbus` connection.

A bit dirty: The `fd` folder also shows me

```
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mär  8 22:45 5 -> /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

`Xorg.0.log` is a clear indication for display `:0`.

---

Another approach: `notify-send` seems to gather `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` with some `dbus` magic. But I have no clue how. That may be the cleanest and most portable way, if at least a dbus daemon is running.

Comment: Added a `w` to my `ps uw` so `ps uww`, now I have both `XAUTHORITY` and `DISPLAY`, it's a good start. I think you have maybe `~/.Xauthority` and `/tmp/xauth*` too

Comment: @GillesQuenot I have neither `~/.Xauthority` nor `/tmp/xauth*`.  And `ps uww $(pidof Xorg)` does not give me `DISPLAY`, sorry.

Comment: Wich distro please ? Very interesting

Comment: @GillesQuenot It is debian 9. But I assume this is rather special to display manager `gdm3` than to debian. I found a hint for `-displayfd 3`, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @GillesQuenot I've added a `systemctl --user show-environment` command.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work in `cron`, so doesn't work for non interactive shell: `Failed to connect to bus`. One solution is to declare `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=xxx` before, that is something maybe possible in my case at install time. Just hope that's a stable PATH (mine is `unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus`)

Comment: The premise of the Desktop Bus/systemd design is that any given user's programs only ever talk to one X server, and all talk to that same one. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231152/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368730/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145167/  The Desktop Bus people claim that there is a default for obtaining the per-user desktop bus broker's socket, [but there are practical problems with that claim](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/gazetteer.html#user-bus-socket).