# How to take a screenshot over SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, environment-variables, screenshot

I have an Ubuntu Desktop machine. My scope is to take a screenshot of this machine via SSH. This machine is playing a video, and I would like to take a screenshot of this video via SSH.
I've tried as root user:

```
root@user-desktop:~# export DISPLAY=:0
root@user-desktop:~# echo $DISPLAY
:0
root@user-desktop:~# scrot screenshot.png
No protocol specified
Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?root@user-desktop:~#
```

Then I've tried with `DISPLAY=:0.0`. instead of `DISPLAY:=0` (I don't know if this matters).

```
root@user-desktop:~# export DISPLAY=:0.0
root@user-desktop:~# echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
root@user-desktop:~# scrot screenshot.png
No protocol specified
Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?root@user-desktop:~#
```

Then I've done the same attempts as non-root user:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ export DISPLAY=:0
user@user-desktop:~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
user@user-desktop:~$ scrot screenshot.png
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCan't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?user@user-desktop:~$

user@user-desktop:~$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
user@user-desktop:~$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
user@user-desktop:~$ scrot screenshot.png
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCan't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?user@user-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Hm, first question: you're running on X, and not on Wayland, right?

Comment: Maybe your ssh block X connections (frequent, for security reasons: most people do not want that a remote program can access so many thing from the local computer). I recommend you to use some screenshot program on your local machine

Comment: Ssh has no chance to block any x connection here, @GiacomoCatenazzi, I think. The X connection doesn't go across ssh

Comment: @MarcusMüller What about sshd configuration: `X11Forwarding`, `AllowTcpForwarding`, etc.? -- ssh builds a tunnel (which eventually several channels). terminal is just one, but we uses a lot ssh to tunnel TCP traffic.

Comment: All irrelevant, since the asker runs the screenshotting program on the machine that is running X, not on a different machine.

Comment: So, the x machine requires a `xhost +`, so that external console programs can access X (programs not opened by X)

Comment: Uff, that would tear down all access control and might not be a good idea on a machine where people can log on via ssh

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, since he runs `scrot` on the same machine that runs the `X11` and using the local display (he doesn't need to actually display anything on the screen, he uses the `DISPLAY` just so `scrot` could take it's screenshot), he doesn't need `xhost +`. It would only be needed if you tried to run `scrot` from a remote machine using the `DISPLAY` of the host he wants to take the screenshot at.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
ssh -x user@user-desktop<<'EOF'
export XAUTHORITY=$(
    ps -u $(id -u) -o pid= |
    xargs -I{} cat /proc/{}/environ 2>/dev/null |
    tr '\0' '\n' |
    grep -m1 '^XAUTHORITY='
)
export DISPLAY=$(
   ps -u $(id -u) -o pid= |
   xargs -I{} cat /proc/{}/environ 2>/dev/null |
   tr '\0' '\n' |
   grep -m1 '^DISPLAY='
)

scrot screenshot.png
EOF
```

Based [on this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429162/12574)

Comment: You have few issues here: 1. The result looking inside the `environ` files will be `DISPLAY=xxx` and `XAUTHORITY=xxx`, which means that `DISPLAY` would actually contain `DISPLAY=xxx` (instead of the actual of value of the `DISPLAY` it found) and `XAUTHORITY` will have `XAUTHORITY=xxx`. 2. If the first process it catches with a `DISPLAY` environment variable is `sshd` (or one of its children), it might use the port forwarded by `ssh` instead of the actual local display.

Comment: 3. The first `ssh` won't work because `scrot` will try to take a screenshot of the `X11` tunnel created by `ssh` instead of the actual local X11 on the destination host. 4. You don't need to use the `-X` flag on your second `ssh`, because you don't want to enable X11 forwarding, since you will change the `DISPLAY` environment variable anyway. It might be even better to disable it with `-x`. 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do it in the same environment and as the same user as that of a process running in that X11 session.

```
sudo -u "$(ps -o user= -p "$pid")" xargs -r0a /proc/"$pid"/environ sh -c '
  env -i -- "$@" scrot -' sh > screenshot.png
```

Where `$pid` could be the pid of some process running `gnome-session` or `xterm` or the window manager for instance in there.