# GTK apps slow if not root

Tags: performance, gtk

Some of my GTK apps (Virt-Manager, Nautilus and EasyTag) are really slow to start when I start them as a normal user, however when they are started as root they start instantly. How can I fix this?

I run on spectrwm windows manager on Debian 10. I start X from the console, and here's a copy of my `xinitrc`:

```
xrdb -load "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/x11/xresources"
compton -b --config "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/compton/compton.conf"
fehbg &
unclutter &
exec spectrwm
```

Comment: @Quasímodo I added some details

Answer (score 2):

Restart your X session after attempting these.

##### [Attempt 1](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1704914#p1704914) (worked for me recently)

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
```

in `.xinitrc` (or whatever you X session file may be) before the `exec` line.

##### Attempt 2 (worked for me in the past)

I found this line in [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit#xinitrc):

> Note: At the very least, ensure that the last if block in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` is present in your `~/.xinitrc`

The last block of the file was:

```
. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

Assuming the same is true for you, add it to your `~/.xinitrc` before the `exec` and see if it helps. For example:

```
xrdb -load "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/x11/xresources"
compton -b --config "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/compton/compton.conf"
fehbg &
unclutter &
. /etc/X11/Xsession
exec spectrwm
```

##### Additional links

- [Gnome programs (eog/gnome-terminal) have a slow start and produce a DBus.Error.NoReply Warning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145167/gnome-programs-eog-gnome-terminal-have-a-slow-start-and-produce-a-dbus-error-n)

Comment: It made the trick but I it looses my keyboard layout. Now Gtk apps show faster but my azerty layout is switched to a qwerty layout.

Comment: I tried to add `setxkbmap -layout fr -model pc105 -variant latin9` in my `xinitrc` before `. /etc/X11/Xsession` but it does'nt take effect.

Comment: Not working either. But when I `killall xinit` and log back in it takes effect.

Comment: Is your keyboard set in `/etc/default/keyboard`? If not, I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: Yes my keyboard is properly defined in `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I had a similar issue and found all these unanswered questions such as yours here. What solved the issue for me was to remove old manually installed libs from `/usr/local/lib` (also see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1877135)

Answer (score 0):

Well idk if it helps or If it helps anyone but still,

I found out that the gtk application conflict between portals
So basically i am using wm and have a desktop for backup purposes
I had 2 desktop portals xdg-desktop-portal-gnome and xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
when i journalctl the system I found that the "Gnome desktop portal " was crashing
so i basically removed xdg-desktop-portal-gnome and everything started working well